# Get object from json based on value using Lodash

Tags: javascript, json, momentjs, lodash

I have the following in json format

```
{
  "timings": {
    "a": "02:57",
    "b": "05:19",
    "c": "13:22",
    "d": "17:39",
    "e": "21:26",
    "f": "21:26",
    "g": "23:40",
    "h": "02:47",
    "i": "01:22"
  }
}
```

Using lodash and momentjs, how I can pick the object whose value is same or after the current time.

I have tried the following

```
let findTime = (times) => {
    const timeNow = moment();
    let nextEvent = null;
    lodash.find(times, function (value, key) {
        const thisTime = moment(value, 'HH:mm');
        if (thisTime.isSameOrAfter(timeNow, 'second')) {
            console.log(key + " is next");
            nextEvent = {
                'name': key,
                'time': value
            };
            return;
        }
    });
    return nextEvent;
}
```

The problem is it keeps returning the item i no matter. I figured that the function find iterate over all the entries.

I am unable to find a different solution.

I need to maintain the order of the times.

Any pointers...?

Comment: You might be better off using the "lodash.each" (or forEach) function found here: https://lodash.com/docs/#forEach And if you are wanting the closest match, you need to keep track of the "last nearest match" separately, and calculate based on the differences between "now" and the time derived from the hash element. Also, have you confirmed that when moment parses the time by HH:mm that it applies the current date (like 5-18-2017), or does it assume 1970?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are trying. The ideal way to use `_.find` is to `return true` for the match (and it will not iterate on next elements).
When you `return true` from your predicate, `_.find` will return you the value of that key.

When you `return true` from your predicate for matching element:

`_.find` returns you the **value** of first match

`_.findLast` returns you the **value** of last match

`_.findKey` returns you the **key** of first match

`_.findLastKey` returns you the **key** of last match

`_.filter` returns you **values** of all the matches as an array

Note: if you want to get the nearest upcoming time, you will need to sort `timings` before passing to any of these lodash functions.

```js
let findTime = (times) => {
    const timeNow = moment();
    let nextEvent = null;
    let ret = _.find(times, function (value, key) {
        const thisTime = moment(value, 'HH:mm');
        if (thisTime.isSameOrAfter(timeNow, 'second')) {
            console.log(key + " is next");
            nextEvent = {
                'name': key,
                'time': value
            };
            return true;
        }
    });
    //return nextEvent;
    return ret; // send the return value from lodash function
}

let times = {
  "timings": {
    "a": "02:57",
    "b": "05:19",
    "c": "13:22",
    "d": "17:39",
    "e": "21:26",
    "f": "21:26",
    "g": "23:40",
    "h": "02:47",
    "i": "01:22"
  }
}
console.log('returned value:', findTime(times.timings));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries()` to iterate `JSON` as `javascript` object, convert date to a whole number using `+` operator and `.replace()`. If condition is `true`, set properties of an object to current property and value.

```js
const data = {
  "timings": {
    "a": "02:57",
    "b": "05:19",
    "c": "13:22",
    "d": "17:39",
    "e": "21:26",
    "f": "21:26",
    "g": "23:40",
    "h": "02:47",
    "i": "01:22"
  }
}

let res = {};

// let now = `${new Date().toJSON()}`.slice(11, 16);

let now = "21:26";

let dateToNumber = str => +str.replace(/:/, "");

for (let [key, prop] of Object.entries(data.timings)) {
  if (dateToNumber(prop) >= dateToNumber(now)) {
    // do stuff
    res[key] =  prop;
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`lodash#findKey`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#findKey) to find a specific key from an object.

```
const findTime = times => {
  let mNow = moment();
  let name = _.findKey(times, v => moment(v, 'HH:mm').isSameOrAfter(mNow));
  var time = times[name];
  return time? { name, time }: null;
};
```

```js
let data = {
  "timings": {
    "a": "02:57",
    "b": "05:19",
    "c": "13:22",
    "d": "17:39",
    "e": "21:26",
    "f": "21:26",
    "g": "23:40",
    "h": "02:47",
    "i": "01:22"
  }
};

const findTime = times => {
  let mNow = moment();
  let name = _.findKey(times, v => moment(v, 'HH:mm').isSameOrAfter(mNow));
  var time = times[name];
  return time? { name, time }: null;
};

console.log(findTime(data.timings));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```